# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__.saved_model' has no attribute 'load'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YAUm.png)

these code where running proprtly few hourse ago.

the problem was solved when imported the files from root files

````
from sklearn import metrics
import tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Dropout,Activation,Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam```
````

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi @Raga, Which TensorFlow version are you using as this code snipped does not show any error when I tried importing these modules in Google Colab using TF 2.12(Attaching the replicated code [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/ffcab86c07caa3dd25b4754cabd3dc88/75917395.ipynb) here). Could you please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) to install tensorflow in your system and try again.